# Spring Kafka does not shutdown properly

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have configured `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` with concurrency of 3 to consume from 3 partitions, and also `KafkaTemplate` with producerFactory that produces messages to 3 partitions. Spring bean is configured with destroy-method to invoke `stop()` of the consumer listener container and the producer at application shutdown time. After shutdown, the log is shown below which looks like consumers has stopped, but there is no info if the producer is stopped or not.

> [kafkaContainer-0-C-1] INFO  org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Consumer stopped
>   [kafkaContainer-2-C-1] INFO  org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Consumer stopped
>   [kafkaContainer-1-C-1] INFO  org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Consumer stopped

but the application is not shutting down completely. Doing a jstack  command shows 3 ThreadPoolTaskScheduler still running in the background. Output snippet of jstack command:

> "ThreadPoolTaskScheduler-1" #74 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f8564f23800 nid=0x77e5 waiting on condition [0x00007f8525292000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
>           at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
>           - parking to wait for  <0x00000000ec8f0808> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The above block is printed for each MessageListener, I mean if I set the concurrency to 5, then jstack output contains the above message 5 times. So I think even if consumer listener is logged as shutdown it is internally not shutting down completely.

I'm I missing something on shutting down the producer and consumer properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say which version you are using.

This is fixed in 2.1.0, 2.0.2 and 1.3.2.

You don't need to `stop()` the container from a `destroy()` method; the context will stop the consumer when it is closed.

Comment: Cool, I was using 1.3.1. Upgrading to 1.3.2 fixed the issue. I'll try to upgrade to even more recent versions. Thank you.

Comment: If you have it handy, please post the link(s) related to that bug, just interested to learn more about that bug. If not that's okay :)

Comment: We added the scheduler to [detect non-responsive consumers here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/467) the bug was found by a community member who submitted a [PR to fix it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/491).